# How to get access for ApplicationpoolIdentity on particular folder

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, web-deployment

My deployed application is creating file on a shared location.

To get it work and allow applicaiton to write file on shared location, I have set applicaiton pool as `domain\user` account.

Please guide me how should i get it working using `applicationpoolidentity` account too ?

Answer (score 1):

Versions of IIS 7.5 and later create a virtual app pool user account running under the umbrella of ApplicationPoolIdentity. This will be unique to that app pool and therefore won't be the same account as on another server.

You'll need to have the same specific local user account or domain user account set as having permissions against both the shared folder and the app pool.